# Please identify this weed in my lawn?

Tags: lawn

I've noticed below weeds at a corner of my front yard.  It appears the weeds are germinating while killing my lawn.  I can see more brown in that area.. I live in Fairfield, CT.

I really appreciate your comments!

[image]

Comment: The way the roots spread looks a bit like [running bamboo](http://www.bamboobotanicals.ca/html/about-bamboo/bamboo-growth-habits.html), but the shoots look too thin for bamboo (in my opinion).

Comment: Well, bamboo is just a type of large grass - and this is a type of grass too, but I don't know which one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks to be Bermudagrass a common weed in your area. If you wish to get rid of this here are your options that I have tried and have had success with.

Spray lawn completely and kill existing turf. Renovate these areas with a stronger form of grass such as Fescue.

Dethatching lawn every fall and overseeding with a stronger form of grass will help keep the lawn green in the winter months when Bermudagrass goes dormant.

Answer (score 1):

The only guaranteed way to get rid of grass species which spread by creeping underground stems is to nuke the entire lawn and start again.

DON'T attempt to dig it out, even after the entire lawn "looks dead" after you nuked it with systemic weed killer. If you leave a 2 millimeter (1/8 inch) piece of root behind, it will regrow. The best option is to leave the area alone till most of the dead vegetation has disappeared, and re-seed the lawn with the absolute minimum of soil disturbance. You only need to "cultivate" the top 1/4 inch of the soil to get grass seed to germinate.

A less drastic method of attack is regular close mowing. If you can keep the weed leaves short, it will eventually die out (but "eventually" may be measured in years, not weeks).